# Which version of photoshop for android

Tags: android, photoshop

I am looking at buying photoshop to be able to use some of the .psd files on the develop.android.com site (eg. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html). In addition, ideally, there would be many tutorials for that version, so I can learn quickly.

I see multiple versions of photoshop; is there a minimum version anyone can recommend which will provide suitable functionality to make basic icons etc?

Comment: Don't think this is off topic - though possibly badly worded

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may wish to force GIMP support by voting here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12271

Answer (score 0):

it compleatly depands on what you want to do with photoshop. 
if you have no idea, i would suggest you check the features of the product at adobe.com.

CS5 is the newest version atm. but for basics any CS version should do it.
if you're really only looking at basic image editing than why not first trying GIMP or paint.net? both are compleatly free of charge and give you the basic abillity you need for skinning.

but if money dosn't matter, take a look at photoshop cs5. or - also depending on what you want to do - you might need adobe illustrator or another vector image editor, or even something more speciallized like fireworks. than maybe the design or master collections from adobe would propably fit best for you (problem: $$$)

if you're a student you can grab a student version of all those products, in fact: you never ever will be able to get photoshop nor any other adobe programms as low as when you're a student. 
hint: on ebay you sometimes can buy student editions from students who don't need them. adobes lizenze policity who does only allow to buy the version if you're a student and only for learning propose dosn't work here, depending on the law in your country.
you could save alot of money that way - but it all depends on your counties law.

greets

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been using GIMP and Inkscape which is ok, but I'd like to be able to use some of the existing material (.psd files etc) and most of the developer documentation refers to photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

go for cs5 trial version when you done just sit back and enjoy.